# UISearchBar losing first responder after reloading data of a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uicollectionview

I have a collection view in an iPad app and wanted to add search functionality. The data source of the collection view is provided by a nsfetchedresultcontroller.

I placed the UISearchBar in a UIToolBar located at the lower part of the window. When the user taps in the search bar I animated the move of the entire toolbar together with the appearance of the keyboard to keep the toolbar (and consequently, the search bar) visible. As the user types in the search bar, I implemented the following method:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if (searchText && searchText.length){
        NSPredicate *searchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[cd] %@", searchText];
        [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:nil];
        [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:searchPredicate];
    }else{
        [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:nil];
        [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:nil];
    }
    [self performFetch];
}
```

My problem is, when the predicate really filters the data set, the toolbar that was placed above the keyboard returns to its original position. If, for instance, what the user typed doesn't not change the data set, the toolbar remains in place.

How can I keep the toolbar in place while the user is typing and, eventually, changing the collection view?

Comment: Why don't place your searchBar in NavigationBar?

Comment: I ended up doing this (placing the searchBar in NavigationBar). But from my original UI design this was not intended. I'll keep trying to figure out a solution for this problem.

Comment: Hi Luiz did found a solution for this problem, I am too having the same issue.Please do inform us if so.

Comment: Facing same problem.